# Middle element in stack

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

I read the article on stack implementation in javascript and python on geeksforgeeks website. I implemented the code to delete the middle element in the stack in javascript exactly as given for python in the same website. But I get wrong answer. Why is it so? what is the difference between the two languages in this case? How can I get the correct answer in javascript? Below is the code in Javascript.

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  push(element) {
    this.items.push(element);
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) {
      return "Underflow";
    } else {
      return this.items.pop();
    }
  }

  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1];
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length == 0;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}

function deleteMid(stack, curr) {

  // If stack is empty or all items 
  // are traversed 

  if (stack.isEmpty() || curr == stack.items.length) {
    return;
  }
  // Remove last item
  x = stack.peek();
  stack.pop();

  // Remove other items 
  deleteMid(stack, curr + 1);
  console.log("length value: ", stack.items.length);

  // Put all items back except middle 
  if (curr != Math.floor(stack.length / 2)) {
    stack.push(x);
  }
}

var stack = new Stack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.print();
deleteMid(stack, 0);
stack.print();
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-middle-element-stack/

Comment: Can you post the output you're getting as well?

Comment: I have added input and output now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some parts of the Python implementation that your implementation misses:

You have an implicitly global `x` variable - unlike Python, in Javascript, variables declared without `var` / `let` / `const` are assigned to the global object, so once the recursive `deleteMid`s have completed, there's only been one variable named `x` (rather than one for each iteration) which you've reassigned every time. Use `const x` instead, to ensure that every call of `deleteMid` has its own binding of `x`.

Your stack does not have a `length` property, so your `curr != Math.floor(stack.length/2)` test results in `curr != NaN` - which isn't what you want. Although you could give your `stack` a `length` getter property:

```
  get length() {
    return this.items.length;
  }
```

this still does not conform to the Python implementation, which *continually recursively passes the initial length*, as another argument: if you want to imitate the Python implementation, do this too, with an `n` variable:

```
function deleteMid(stack, n, curr) {
  // ...
  // Remove other items 
  deleteMid(stack, n, curr + 1);
  // Put all items back except middle 
  if (curr != Math.floor(n / 2)) {
  // ...
// Call with:
deleteMid(stack, stack.items.length, 0);
```

The problem with checking the `length` property is that it will change *while you're iterating*, which will make things much more difficult to work with.

For the same reason, so that even sized stacks work, we also need to change your JS test here:

```
if (stack.isEmpty() || curr == stack.items.length) {
```

to correspond to the Python code:

```
if (st.isEmpty() or curr == n) :
```

Working code:

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  push(element) {
    this.items.push(element);
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) {
      return "Underflow";
    } else {
      return this.items.pop();
    }
  }

  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1];
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length == 0;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.items);
  }
  get length() {
    return this.items.length;
  }
}

function deleteMid(stack, n, curr) {

  // If stack is empty or all items 
  // are traversed 

  if (stack.isEmpty() || curr === n) {
    return;
  }
  // Remove last item
  const x = stack.peek();
  stack.pop();

  // Remove other items 
  deleteMid(stack, n, curr + 1);

  // Put all items back except middle 
  if (curr != Math.floor((n) / 2)) {
    stack.push(x);
  }
}

var stack = new Stack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.print();
deleteMid(stack, stack.items.length, 0);
stack.print();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The reason why I did not pass the parameter 'n' is I thought stack.items.length would remain constant and so I could pass only the stack and index parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the middle index when you start, you can check the stack's length after each item's removal, and stop when you hit the middle.

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  push(element) {
    this.items.push(element);
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.items.length === 0) {
      return "Underflow";
    } else {
      return this.items.pop();
    }
  }

  peek() {
    return this.items[this.items.length - 1];
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.items.length == 0;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}

function deleteMid(stack, middle = Math.round(stack.items.length / 2)) {
  if (stack.isEmpty()) return;
  
  const isMiddle = stack.items.length === middle;
  
  // Remove last item
  const x = stack.pop();

  // stop when you get to the middle
  if (isMiddle) return;
  
  // Remove other items
  deleteMid(stack, middle);
  
  // add the item back
  stack.push(x);
}

var stack = new Stack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.print();
deleteMid(stack);
stack.print();
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it! I had tried this approach before but I did not get the correct answer. I am still getting used to Javascript way of programming!

Comment: Can u please explain what is happening at this line? const isMiddle = stack.items.length === middle;

Comment: ` stack.items.length === middle` is a boolean expression (returns `true` or `false`), and the result of the expression is assigned to `isMiddle`.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! Understood. It is just like returning true or false and assigning the value.